# setOnItemClickListener not working in android 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

I have a `listView` with `baseAdapter` and I want to use set `onItemClickListener` in my activity and that works good in most of the phones except LG's phones with android 6.0.1?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_country"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/india"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="India"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/text_country"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my `listview` code snippet**

```
languagesListAdapter = new LanguagesListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), prepareDataCountryList());
    listView.setAdapter(languagesListAdapter);

       @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(languagesListAdapter.languagesToTranslates.get(position).getImagges());


    linearLayoutselectLanguageToTranslate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mInputView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    constraintLayoutBellowKeyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your text will be translated in " +
            languagesListAdapter.languagesToTranslates.get(position).getLanguae(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("languageToTranslatInstantText",
            languagesListAdapter.languagesToTranslates.get(position).getCodeCountry()).apply();
    languageToTranslate = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("languageToTranslatInstantText", "en");

}
```

Here I implemented `onItemClickListener`

This code is working good everywhere except android 6.0.1 on Lg phone!!
Help!!

Comment: share log cats here

Comment: This looks like a good chance to learn about debugger and breakpoints.

Comment: I don't see a line where you set the listener.

Comment: You must share your logcat of that phone error. But I suggest you to use `parent.getAdapter().languagesToTranslates.get(position).getImagges()` instead of `languagesListAdapter.languagesToTranslates.get(position).getImagges()`. It is safer way to access to adapter.

Comment: if you have one of these devices: have you tested if it enters into onItemClick method?

Comment: No it not entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't hookup your list view with the itemclicklistener. If you implemented the interface to the whole class, you should do this:

```
listview.setOnItemClicklistener(this);
```

Comment: I did that evrithing is good working in all devices expect LG with android 6.0.1

Comment: Probably the device has a software/hardware problem

Comment: No beaucause I checked 3 devices LG with this android version and bug is evrywhere

Comment: I solved the problem with RecyclerView and an Interface for on itemClickListener!!